# Relation between colections of Borel sets and open sets for a full support measure.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $(X, \mathcal{U})$ be a compact metric space and $\mu$ be a Borel probability measure such that $supp(\mu)=X$, $supp(\mu)$ is the support of $\mu$. Also take $\mathcal{A}^+_X= \{A\in B_X: \mu(A)>0\}$ where $B_X$ is the set of Borel sets of $X$.

What can say about relation $\mathcal{A}^+_X$ and $\mathcal{U}$? Is it true that $\mathcal{U}\subseteq \mathcal{A}^+_X$?

Comment: What is $\mathcal U$? And what is your definition of support? What do you think?

Comment: So if a nonempty open $U$ has $\mu(U)=0$, then ${\rm supp}(\mu) \subseteq X\setminus U$, basically by definition of support, hence $U=\emptyset$ follows according to the hypothesis.

Answer (score 2):

If $\mathcal U$ is supposed to be Borel sigma algebra the answer is NO. Consider Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ and the set $\{0\}$. This has measure $0$ even though the support of $\mu$ is $[0,1]$.

The support is $[0,1]$ because every non-empty set has positive measure.

If $\mathcal U$ is supposed to be the  class of all open sets then  an element $U$ of  $\mathcal U$ belongs to $\mathcal A_X^{+}$ iff it is non-empty.

Comment: It seems that $U$ is meant to be the topology on $X.$ But $\emptyset$ is open and has measure $0$.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy, Thanks for your reply. Yes $\mathcal{U}$ is the class of all open sets. Can we say that $\mathcal{U}-\{\emptyset\} = \mathcal{A}^+_X$?